# Ubuntu Server VNC Connection

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vnc

I am trying to access my Ubuntu Server with Chicken of the VNC. I have GNOME installed on the server to which I can get access if I log onto the server locally and COTVNC will discover the server then through Bonjour service. Yet if I restart the server and do not log in locally then I have issues where my VNC Client does not discover the server any longer through Bonjour and I cannot connect even with manually inputting the IP address. I get Connection timed out error message from the client.

Any ideas how I can get around this as I do not want to have a keyboard and mouse connected to this server as it will be used as a media server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start vnc server as a seperate service via /etc/init or /etc/init.d, and not as part of the session.

Comment: Okay thanks I have modified that file with nano but it didn't let me connect after reboot. Perhaps it was the script I was using. Can u suggest something I could use please? 

Thanks

Comment: Is the server reachable via network at all, e.g. ssh?

Comment: Yes I can remotely SSH

Comment: Is there a vncserver running on the system? ps aux | grep -i vnc should show this. Also, is the port listened too? netstat -tape should show this.

Comment: yes I done an apt get-install vnc4server and installed that, I used ufw to open the port 5900 so that I could get access. Although according to netstat -tape its 5901 listening. Also x11-1 seems to be listening for VNC4 server but not sure what that means

Comment: from your host, can you telnet to the server port 5901? Or is there maybe a router or firewall between that blocks the traffic. tracepath for the ip of the server might show that.

Comment: On telnet I get connect to address operation timed out. Unable to connect to remote host. I couldnt do tracepath from terminal on my mac but doing it remotely on the server (I entered the IP address of my host machine)I got the following:

 1:  ubuntuFileServer.local                                0.167ms pmtu 1500
 1:  Nathans-MacBook-Pro.local                             4.992ms reached
 1:  Nathans-MacBook-Pro.local                             4.442ms reached
     Resume: pmtu 1500 hops 1 back 64

Comment: Like I said it connects fine once the user has logged onto the server, I am just not sure how to get remotely connected after restarting the machine

Comment: While probably not dealing with the root cause, if you can ssh to the server, probably try to setup ssh port forwarding from localhost 5901 to server 5901, have a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC